# How to write good email for applying leaves

Tags: creative-writing, word-choice, email

I want to write polite mail for applying leaves. As of now I have written this, I am going wrong please correct me or suggest better way to do that

> Subject: Apply Leave.
>    Hi sir, I am writing this to let you know that I need leaves from Dec
>   7, Dec 15, 2019. I will come office to Dec 16. If any issue please
>   call me.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi Arvindraja! Welcome to Writing.SE! I'm afraid your question is off topic for us: we do not critique individual pieces of writing, but focus on general writing technique, including styles, tropes etc. You can find out more on our [tour] and [help] pages. I see English is not your first language. But you need to communicate with your boss in English? [ell.se] *might* be able to help you, but you would need to see what exactly is or isn't on topic for them.

Comment: @Galastel - Yeah I am communicating my boss in English only since the language boss knows(Telugu) I don't know & the language I know(Hindi) that boss don't know. So the English is bridge. I am sure ELL not going to accept this too. Thank you.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - is leave*s* (as in "leave of absence") a typical word in British English? In American English, I just could not think past "tree leaves".

Comment: Hello, this is off topic but I will just say that, in American English at least, you would say "I need a leave of absence."  While a "request" or "application" for leave is grammatically correct, you would only use it if the boss can say no to you.  It sounds like you're telling your boss and not asking for permission.

Comment: @Alexander - This is about leave of absence. Can I use word _leaves_ if leave more than one. Thank you.

Comment: @Arvindraja The plural phrase is *leaves of absence*.

Comment: @JasonBassford - Thank you. Last question, Is it mandatory to add _of absence_, can't we say only _leaves_ because many people here saying 'Leave of absence'.

Comment: @Arvindraja You normally add *of absence*, yes. But you can also simply ask for *time off* or to *take vacation* (if you have the latter available). The only time I'd expect to hear just *leave* would be in the military—although I'm only going by books, movies, and news when I say that, not from personal experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are not supposed to critique or suggest, but this could be important, so here goes:

‘Hi’ is informal. The more appropriate form in this situation is ‘dear sir’ or just ‘sir’.

‘Dear sir, I wish to apply for leave from December 7th to December 15 for (insert reason here). If this causes any issues, please call me at (insert number).

Thank you.

You could even thank him for his time and consideration. I tend to add those myself.

Comment: "Dear Mr. [surname]" is fairly standard as an opening.

Comment: As a non english speaker: is "Dear sir" in use? It sounds strange to me, but who knows.

Comment: @Liquid "Dear Sir" is very common in American business, nobody thinks it is unusual. Unless your boss is a female; then I think most people would use "Dear Ms. Jones". For equality's sake, I'd use "Dear Mr. Jones" for a male superior.

Comment: @Amadues Thanks for pointing that out for me.

Comment: There is also Dear Sir or Madam or Dear Madam

Comment: @Liquid I worked in a business environment for quite some time. I never once encountered "Dear Sir." It sounds quite strange. I didn't even encounter "Dear" in any internal business correspondence. It was always Mr. or Ms. (or Mrs. if you knew the woman was married) followed by the last name. If you were on a first name basis, then the first name was used. If I were writing to my manager, I would certainly never use "Dear Sir."